# Storm UI showing Different Numbers of Executors and Tasks

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I am using storm with trident topology but I am not able to understand how the parallelism is attained, it is differing according to my calculation and what I seeing on storm UI,

Here's the code the assign number of workers:

```
public Config getTopologyConfiguration() {
    Config conf = new Config();
    //conf.setDebug(true);
    conf.setNumWorkers(6);
    conf.setMessageTimeoutSecs(100);
    return conf;
}
```

And Here is the stream processing code:

```
s.name("aggregation_stream")
            .parallelismHint(invoiceAggregationConfig.getSpoutParallelism())
            .partitionBy(groupedFields)
            .partitionAggregate(aggregateInputFields,
                    new GenericAggregator(groupedFields, aggregatedFieldsList, aggregateFieldsOperationList),
                    aggregatorOutputFields)
            .parallelismHint(invoiceAggregationConfig.getAggregationParallelism())
            .shuffle()
            .each(aggregatorOutputFields,
                    new CreatePaymentFromInvoices(paymentType, groupMap, aggMap, paymentExtraParams),
                    Const.PAYMENT_FIELD)
            .each(TridentUtils.fieldsConcat(aggregatorOutputFields, Const.PAYMENT_FIELD),
                    new CreateApplicationFromPaymentAndInvoices(invoiceType),
                    Const.APPLICATIONS_FIELD)
            .each(TridentUtils.fieldsConcat(aggregatorOutputFields, Const.PAYMENT_FIELD, Const.APPLICATIONS_FIELD),
                    new RestbusFilterForPaymentAndApplications(environment, bu, serviceConfiguration))
            .parallelismHint(invoiceAggregationConfig.getPersistenceParallelism());
```

and the parallelism attributes which I am using in the code above are here:

```
spoutParallelism: 3
aggregationParallelism: 6
persistenceParallelism: 6
```

Now according to my calculation the number of executors should be 
3*6 + 6 = 24

But in Storm UI it is showing 23, how??

[image]

**EDITED**

Adding new screenshot which is having information about individual components

[image]

Here I can see the number of Executors and tasks are 50, but I didn't set any configuration to for this, does storm provide this itself??

Secondly, The number of emitted tuples is huge in number, I am not producing this much data,this is more than 100s times more tuples,  how come this much tuples are showing in UI??

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of individual components.. I believe this has to do with acking and also let us know how many slots are empty on the cluster

Comment: @supermonk : I have edited the question. please check

Comment: Please post the full code of building and submitting the topology

Answer (score 0):

Number of emitted tuples can be huge number 
 Reason : when spout emit a tuple it will expect the ack, if ack not received it will resend the tuple so emitted and transferred count can be a higher value.  (check ack count its small number with compare to emitted count)

Comment: please check ack count it should be < produced data record count